# Backbone - receiving DELETE data in the back end

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, webapp2

Say you have a model with an `id`, and you want to delete it in the database. So you call the `destroy()` method on that model (as below in the code example). That sends an `OPTIONS` HTTP request, followed by a `DELETE` HTTP request. My issue is that while I'm catching the `DELETE` request nicely on the server side, I can't find any information telling me what the model `id` is - it's not a parameter in the request and it's not in the URL. How do I find this information? I can't see it in the documentation [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy). Here is a [link](https://github.com/bengrunfeld/gae-backbone-todos) to the repo where I'm storing the code.

```
  removeElement: function() {
    // DELETE in DB
    this.model.destroy();
    this.remove();
    this.unbind();
  },
```

What I would expect is that the HTTP request would have a param like `{ 'id': 42319 }` or some such.

Comment: It should be in the url alright. http://blabla/resource/id should be the resource to delete.

Comment: Here's the address that's being generated: `http://localhost:8080/todos/api/v0.1.0/`. Is the `id` of the model somehow not being set?

Comment: You can check out the Network panel to see if the id is set. The url should have the resource after the version number of the api, followed by the resource id. But all of this depends on how you set up your backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was defining the `url` attribute in BOTH the `model` AND the `collection`. You should only define `url` in the `collection`. Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set the model ID attribute. The id set automatically by Backbone on the client is cid and not id. Note that a common gotcha with DBs that use a different unique key (like MongoDB) is not mapping from that key to ID [as described in the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute)

For example:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "_id"
    //other model setup code
});
```

Comment: when I add `attribute: 'id',` to the model (like in your example), it stops sending a HTTP request to the server - hence, something is crashing somewhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming you have the urlRoot set, and the necessary route setup correctly on your server - it may be because you are not creating an ID when you create the model. This [example app](https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-cellar/blob/master/tutorial/part3/js/main.js) might help you. Be sure to look at the `wineDetails` function

Comment: Will look over it tomorrow. If it solves my issue, I'll mark your answer correct. Thanks =)